# How do I select a color range selection via Photoshop Python Api

Tags: python-3.x, photoshop

Here are some of my attempts:

```
selRef  = doc.selection()
sel_area = ((0, 0), (1, 0), (0,1), (1, 1))
#selRef.select(sel_area, ps.SelectionType.DiminishSelection, 0, False)
#selRef.SelectAll()

selRef.SelectAll()
width = int(doc.Width)
height = int(doc.Height)
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        selRef.select([(i, j)], ps.SelectionType.ReplaceSelection)
```

But ps does not provide a corresponding function or object. Has anyone written a similar function or method?